# Getting "Nullable object must have a value." during TFS 2018.3 to Azure DevOps Server 2019 upgrade

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, upgrade

So I'm upgrading a TFS 2018.3 on premises deployment to the new Azure DevOps Server 2019. After I installed the new server when I get to the screen to select SQL Server instance/DB I get the above error. After that the config wizard stalls completely and I have to kill it from Task Manager.

The Application Layer is on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server, fully patched.

The DB layer is on Windows Server 2012 R2, SQL 2017 (14.0.2002.14).

Nothing useful in the Event Log or the the upgrade logs.

Does anyone experienced this problem or has an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the server wasn't upgraded to TFS 2018.3 and this was causing problems. After upgrading to the latest TFS 2018 the update worked.